# Using Custom Vectors in C

Tags: c, vector

I'm fairly new to C/C++, but I'm trying to debug some code. It uses a vector that someone had called CART8 and is structured as such:

```
typedef struct crt8 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z; } CART8;
```

Now my question is this. How do I create and populate an instance of an vector of type CART8 called vector1? I've read through a lot of material, and even found a site that indicate how you would create the vector...as indicated above, but no information on HOW to actually use it.

Comment: So you read the wrong material. Try a basic `C` language book instead. The section about structures.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are mistaken about the terminology. Your code shows a struct, not a vector. Are you trying to create an object of that type, or create a vector of structs?

Comment: @rtmh op refers to a ds that describes a vector, not a C++ vector (;

Comment: @Ishay Peled, ahhh, haha! My mistake, I've been buried in a lot of (c++) vectors myself lately, so definitely jumped to conclusions! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef` is used extensively in C to refer to `struct` variables without specifying the `struct` prefix, for example if I had:

```
struct vector {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

than to initialize it I'd have to do:

```
struct vector vector1;
vector1.x = 1.11;
vector1.y = 1.22;
vector1.z = 1.33;
```

But if I used a `typedef` in the declaration:

```
typedef struct vector {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    } vector_type;
```

than I could simplify this initialization like so (note the struct prefix is not needed now):

```
vector_type vector1;
vector1.x = 1.11;
vector1.y = 1.22;
vector1.z = 1.33;
```

Of course, I could still use the full `struct vector` initialization in this case as well

So in your case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct crt8 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} CART8;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CART8 vector1;
    vector1.x = 2.526;
    vector1.y = 3.416;
    vector1.z = 4.32;
    printf("%f %f %f\n", vector1.x, vector1.y, vector1.z);
}
```

Alternatively, you can always resort to the original struct definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct crt8 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} CART8;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    struct crt8 x;
    x.x = 2.341;
    x.y = 3.43;
    x.z = 4.521;
    printf("%f %f %f\n", x.x, x.y, x.z);
}
```

Comment: Since the person is new, id explicitly format the numbers as floating point since the struct is 3 doubles.

Comment: Shorter: `struct vector {double x, y, z;} v = {3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};`

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Wow! I've never seen that. Does that have to do with a deafult constrcutor or how does that work? Is this related to C++11's initializer lists?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs of course you could! But judging by this question, op is kinda beginner in C and I don't want to confuse

Comment: @rtmh No, this is pure C. Also, since C99 you can use this syntax as well: `vector v2 = {.x = 3.0f, .z = 5.0f}; /* y = 0.0f */`

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs `f` suffix is for `float` not `double`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yeah. Just noticed.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs thanks, fixed in answer as well. Easy to overlook (;

Comment: @IshayPeled No, for printing doubles you use `%f`, since there is no format specifier for double. If you use scientific format `%e`, you will get this type of output: `1.500000E+00`.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

```
typedef struct crt8 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} CART8;
```

This defined a new 'type'. The 'typename' is `struct crt8` or the alias you defined `CART8`. This is how you instantiate an object from that type in C:

```
    struct crt8 myVector;
```

or you can use the alias 'CART8' that you've defined:

```
    CART8 myVector;
```

Either way, this is how you populate the 'members' of your object:

```
    CART8 x; // Creation of object
    x.x = 100;
    x.y = 101;
    x.z = 102;
```

Comment: @KMulier No Problem, it's not like I don't mind the rep!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows various ways how objects of the structure can be created, initialized, and used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct crt8 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z; } CART8;

int main( void ) 
{
    CART8 vector1 = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };

    CART8 vector2 = { .x = 1.1, .y = 2.2, .z = 3.3 };

    CART8 vector3;
    vector3.x = 1.1;
    vector3.y = 2.2;
    vector3.z = 3.3;

    CART8 vector4 = vector1;

    CART8 vector5 = { vector1.x + vector2.z, vector1.y + vector2.y, vector1.z + vector2.x };

    printf( "vector5 = { %lf, %lf, %lf }\n", vector5.x, vector5.y, vector5.z );

    printf( "Magnitude = %lf", sqrt( pow( vector1.x, 2 ) + pow( vector1.y, 2 ) + pow( vector1.z, 2 ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
vector5 = { 4.400000, 4.400000, 4.400000 }
Magnitude = 4.115823
```